# Making a data class

Tags: java

Just testing around with java, and i cant seem to get this to return the object. It just returns null

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Data {

    private static HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();

    private String key;
    private Object content;

    public Data(String key, boolean bool) {
        this.key = key;
        this.content = bool;
    }

    public Data(String key, String string) {
        this.key = key;
        this.content = string;
    }

    public Data(String key, int integer) {
        this.key = key;
        this.content = integer;
    }

    public Data(String key, double double_) {
        this.key = key;
        this.content = double_;
    }

    public Object createData(String key, Object content) {
        data.put(key, content);
        return data.get(key);
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data.get(key);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is returning null?

Comment: Sorry this didnt post: 
public class Testing {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Data data = new Data("test_int", 11010);
  System.out.println(data.getData());
 }
 
}

Comment: Do not post code into a comment! Edit the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not putting your value into map in any constructor, therefore `data.get` method always returns null, so change your constructors like:

```
public Data(String key, boolean bool) {
    this.key = key;
    this.content = bool;
    createData(key,bool); // or directly call put here like data.put(key, bool);
}
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with this class but I have to say, it's pretty dirty and not good since it points out a static map in a POJO.

Don't forget you have to change all of your constructors.